# Using Indexes on a base table

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

If I have two tables, A and B, where A is indexed on A.i and A.ii, while B is indexed on B.i, and I run the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A JOIN B
     on A.i = B.i
```

I understand that this will use the index on B, but would I get any performance gains (i.e., use the index on A) if I use the following query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM A JOIN B
     on A.i = B.i AND A.ii = B.ii
```

My gut instinct tells me no, and [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html) MySQL documentation suggests that I'd need to use a WHERE clause on A.i and A.ii to see any benefits, but I'd like more than an educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there would be any gain by joining also on A.ii it would be lost by including unindexed B.ii. So no, no gain.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports [index merge optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-merge-optimization.html), so it could use the two indexes on B and find the intersection between them.  You'll notice this in the EXPLAIN output when `type: index_merge` and `keys: i,ii` and there will also be a note in the `Extra` field showing that it's using intersection.

But if you have equality comparisons combined as `AND` terms, it's far better to define a compound index on the pair of columns.
See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/19/multi-column-indexes-vs-index-merge/

MySQL 5.6 also provides [index condition pushdown](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html), which helps in some cases even if you have only an index on B.i, and B.ii has no index at all.